# is it possible to send values from one form to other forms in java

Tags: java

I always thought Java was pass-by-reference; however I've seen a couple of blog posts (for example, this blog) by the way

How to send values of variables of one form to another form , like if there is variable `int a` in form 1 and some one want to show value of value of `a` in form 2, then how to do this ? I've tried this code but its not working. correct me if i am wrong

```
/*form 1*/  
String n1=txt.getText();
    frm2 j=new frm2(n1);
    j.setVisible(true);
/*form 2*/
 public frm2( String n) {
    initComponents(); String u=n;
}
```

Comment: This is the basic concept of OOPs read passing value/objects from one class to other..

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want. You should have more complete code to demonstrate. Note: follow coding conventions. Type names (classes, interfaces, enums) should start with a capital letter. Indentation is important. Give variables meaningful names, not `j`, `n1`, `n` etc. - otherwise your code is unreadable. And when you have a question, give context - at the very least the declarations of all the variables you are using and all the methods you are calling that are not in the standard library.